# Put OpenFeint or GameCenter in my iOS App

Tags: iphone, game-center, openfeint

Many Games like 'Angry bird' have a 'OpenFeint' or 'GameCenter' button. click it bring you to a page.

I want to use OpenFeint or GameCenter in my Game,how can I do it?

Comment: You'd be better off by reading their official documentation first instead of asking this on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Openfeint and include GameKit in your game as well. And you can use both already..